I'm not able to see a button Yes and No
After 6 attempts I'm not getting the buttons rendered in the page. I tried to debug but i'm not understanding. Below is the code for the componenet and everything is working as expected except the button yes and no.
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {useRef} from "react";
function Game() {
    const p1Ref = useRef(null);
  const p2Ref = useRef(null);
  const p3Ref = useRef(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const inputRef = useRef(0);
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    inputRef.current.value = event.target.value;
  };
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  let count = 0;
  
  let v3 = [];

  function calculate() {    
    if (count == 5) {
      p2Ref.current.innerHTML = "You lost";
      p3Ref.current.innerHTML = "Gameover";
      count = 0;
      v3 = [];
    } else if (inputRef.current.value === randomNumber) {
      p1Ref.current.innerHTML = "Your guess is right. The random number chosen is: " + randomNumber;
      p2Ref.current.innerHTML = "you have guessed in " + v3.length + " chances";
      p3Ref.current.innerHTML = "Gameover";
      count = 0;
      v3 = [];
    } else if (inputRef.current.value > randomNumber) {
      p1Ref.current.innerHTML = "your guess is high";
      v3[count] = inputRef.current.value;
      count = count + 1;
      p2Ref.current.innerHTML = "your guesses: " + v3.join(", ");
    } else {
      p1Ref.current.innerHTML = "your guess is low";
      v3[count] = inputRef.current.value;
      count = count + 1;
      p2Ref.current.innerHTML = "your guesses: " + v3.join(", ");
    }

    if (p3Ref.current.innerHTML === "Gameover") {
        console.log("im inside")
      return (
        <div>
          <button>
            Yes
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => navigate("/next")}>
            No
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="mad">
      <h1><b>Number guessing game</b></h1>
      <pre>
        <p id="p4">
          We have selected a random number between 1 and 100. See if you can guess it in 6 turns or fewer.
          <br />
          We&apos;ll tell you if your guess was too high or too low.
        </p>
      </pre>
      <div className="prompt1">
        Enter the prompt: <input type="number" required min="1" max="100" id="input1"  ref={inputRef} onChange={handleInputChange}></input>
        <button id="done" onClick={calculate}>submit</button>
      </div>
      <p ref={p1Ref}></p>
      <p ref={p2Ref}></p>
      <p ref={p3Ref}></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Game;

I'm not understanding why it's not rendering as it's going inside and priniting in i'm inside in console.

Why do you use a ref innerHTML when you have React? I'm pretty sure you'll have less problems if you migrate your component to useState()

There are a variety of things wrong here.  Whatever React tutorial or example led you to this code, you might want to try a different one.  You appear to be trying to directly modify the DOM, which will lead to a variety of bugs in React if you don't know what you're doing.  You're also trying to return markup from a click handler, which doesn't do anything in React or JavaScript in general.  You'll probably want to start over with some introductory tutorials on React.

Basically... You'd use state to conditionally render your buttons, and simply update that state in your click handler.  Though doing so in the code shown may easily break the various manual DOM updates you're making.

I would start from scratch using the official "Getting started" documentation.

In React we don't mutate the DOM. In React the UI is a function of state and props, so if you are wanting to update the rendered UI then you'll need to update some state/props and trigger a component rerender.

Unfortunately, as others have pointed out, this code sample is swimming upstream in many ways and to such a degree that it is unlikely to be answered clearly and concisely. There are some helpful comments here already that can hopefully get you on the right track. For the time being I'm voting to close this as being overly broad (needing focus)—questions like this are a bad fit for Stack Overflow’s format and unlikely to wind up helpful for others in the future, but please don't let it discourage you in the future.

Thank you all for your help. To make it more clear its a simple javascript code which I've written and I was curious that how it works in react and I used use state but it renders the whole component so it doesnt work . So I saw a hooks which is useref so I used it. Although I was satisfied that the logic was working then I thought of let me return something using DOM but I was failing at this step. I tried to understand why it wasn't rendering but i failed. That's why I posted this question. Anyways I guess I need to start from scratch.

Nothing is render because you are using useRef() hook which doesn't cause re-render. When any action happened react know that there is no need to re-render due to useRef.

My question is  if p3Ref.current.innerHTML === "Gameover" it should return . When i debugged this it's going inside the statement. The condition passed now return should work right? but why isn't returning?

@Jhadtheelasainischalsatwikqame FWIW that calculate will always return unless it throws an exception. Most of the time it returns nothing, and sometimes it returns that JSX. BUT the "issue" is that nothing cares at all about any return value, e.g. there's nothing with this sort of code: const result = calculate();. As David mentioned in their comment, you are trying to return markup from an event handler, and there is nothing there to receive/handle it.

React is not something that you use with your existing pages like you would with jQuery. With React, you describe your applications with Components that re-render when state changes. Components return React elements, usually with JSX syntax. JSX is syntactic sugar and even though it looks like HTML, it is not HTML. When you write return <p>some text</p>, you are NOT writing nor returning HTML. You are writing JSX and returning React elements. The React elements are then converted to DOM nodes and reconciled with your actual DOM (or other representations, depending on your runtime).
To answer your immediate problem: the buttons don't show, because you are not returning them from your component. You are returning JSX from a click handler on another button – but click handlers can't return anything and if they do, the return value is completely ignored.
And even if you fixed that, your component still wouldn't work. Why not? Because every time it is re-rendered, your function is called again, generating a new random number.

Now, there's a lot more going on in your example that you wouldn't see in an idiomatic React application. What's up with all the useRef calls? What's up with setting innerHTML directly on the DOM?
Here's one approach to make this more idiomatic:

Drop all the refs
Add 3 state variables:

The random number. Initialized once for each component. Render your component with a custom key (<Game key="mykey" />) to get a new random number
The current (unsubmitted) input value. Updated on change
A list of guesses of the player. The number of attempts and the current/latest guess can be derived from this state


Check if the current guess is the correct one and if it is, return early with whatever you want to display to the player (your yes/no buttons, if I understood correctly)
If the number of guesses exceeds the limit, show the lose message
Else, render your form and conditionally display the hint (too low/high) and the list of player guesses.

This separates logic from state from representation. Submitting a guess only requires to add it to the list of guesses. The rest is derived from this state and the component returns different JSX depending on the current state. Fewer lines of code, less repetition, clearer data flow. That's how you do React.
Expressed in code:
function Game() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [randomNumber] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(0);
    const [guesses, setGuesses] = useState([]);
    const count = guesses.length;
    const currentGuess = count ? guesses[count - 1] : null;

    const handleInputChange = event => setInputValue(event.target.value);
    const calculate = () => setGuesses(a => [...a, inputValue]);

    if (currentGuess == randomNumber) {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Your guess is right. The random number chosen is {randomNumber}</p>
                <p>you have guessed in {count} chances</p>
                <p>Gameover</p>
                <div>
                    <button>Yes</button>
                    <button onClick={() => navigate("/next")}>No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } else if (count >= 6) {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>You lost</p>
                <p>Gameover</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="mad">
            <h1>Number guessing game</h1>
            <pre>
                <p id="p4">
                    We have selected a random number between 1 and 100. See if you can guess it in 6 turns or fewer.
                    <br/>
                    We&apos;ll tell you if your guess was too high or too low.
                </p>
            </pre>
            <div className="prompt1">
                Enter the prompt: <input type="number" required min="1" max="100" id="input1" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange}></input>
                <button id="done" onClick={calculate}>submit</button>
            </div>
            {guesses.length > 0
                ? <>
                    {currentGuess > randomNumber ? <p>your guess is high</p> : null}
                    {currentGuess < randomNumber ? <p>your guess is low</p> : null}
                    <p>your guesses: {guesses.join(", ")}</p>
                  </>
                : null}
        </div>
    );
}

